# Выпадающие меню

Tags: android, android-layout

Мне нужно реализовать вот такое меню (только у меня оно будет в правом верхнем углу):

[image]

Думаю что это не `spinner`, больше похоже на `popup`. Мне нужно это меню `actionbar'e` там есть возможность вложить меню в `item` и получить `popup`, но он имеет отступы справа (не полностью прилегает к концу экрана), да и в новых версиях `android'a` оно накладывается на `actionbar`, но это вроде поправимо с помощью `dropDownVerticalOffset` и `overlapAnchor`.

Собственно вопрос, можно ли как нибудь с помощью стилей `actionbar'a` добиться желаемого отображения (что бы в плотную прилегало к границе экрана, типа подменю), или для этого нужно создавать свой собственный `popup` или даже собственный `view`?

Если есть какие нибудь материалы по моей проблеме, буду признателен если напишите ссылки...

Upd

Убрал actionbar вместо него поставил toolbar.
Соответственно это повлияло на стили, задача такая:

1. сместить всплывающее окно в правый верхний угол, что бы не было отступов от края;
2. изменить цвет и размер текста;
3. изменить ширину этого блока (что бы было `wrap_content`);
4. поменять цвет разделителей, и цвет Selector'a.

Сейчас в интернете икал, по нему пока совсем мало инфы, ребят подскажите как стилизовать все это дело, а то я так дня два еще буду искать как это сделать...

Вот пока что у меня есть:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/OverflowMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="OverflowMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
    <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">-4.0dip</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Ps. какой-то неудобный здесь редактор, тут есть старый добрый bbcode?

Comment: если вы нашли решение на свой вопрос самостоятельно - оформите его в качестве ответа. Это поможет другим решить аналогичную проблему быстрее.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для создания контекстного меню страницы в активити надо переописать метод:

```
/**
 * Создание контекстного меню страницы
 */
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.page_context_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

page_context_menu.xml выглядит примерно так:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/item_1"
          android:title="Item 1"
          android:orderInCategory="1"
          android:icon="@drawable/my_icon"
          app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/item_2"
          android:title="Settings"
          android:orderInCategory="2"
          app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

Отрисовкой всего этого занимается андроид, поэтому если надо, чтобы выглядело как-то нестандартно, придется рисовать меню самостоятельно.

Comment: Почему вы решили что это контекстное меню? Что значит рисовать самостоятельно? Делать новый view или свой popup? мне не понятен ваш ответ

Comment: У вас на скриншоте нарисовано контекстное меню страницы, которое рисуется, когда нажимаешь на кнопку в actionBar с тремя точками. Я и привел пример, как его сделать. Но можно все то же самое нарисовать руками. Вопрос в том, насколько вас устроит стандартное решение.

Comment: Как я понял, тот код нужно в активности разместить, да создается подменю при клике на иконку, но почему вы его называете контекстным если оно всплывающие (popup), и как я уже писал выше, остается отступ справа от границы экрана, который нужно убрать. И каким способом это сделать, вот в чем и вопрос, возможно ли с помощью каких popup styles атрибутов это сделать, или нужно создавать свое popup меню, или же и вовсе свой view?

Comment: если вам нужно именно в правом верхнем углу, то написанный вариант идеально подходит. Весь остальной визуал можно будет настроить в стилях

Comment: Вот уже есть половина ответа, то есть можно настроить расположение этого меню справа (без отступов от границы экрана)? Подскажите пожалуйста какие стили мне нужно затронуть что бы изменить это, желательно что бы изменения касались только это меню в actionbar'e

Comment: да, в стилях можете использовать margin и padding.

Comment: Всем спасибо, с помощью стилей все сделал. Немного сложновато правда стилизация этого всплывающего меню...